# Icons disappeared from my desktop in Windows 10, only the names remain

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, troubleshooting, icons, desktop

Today I tried installing a Virtual XP and Windows 7 PC on my computer using Oracle VirtualBox. I downloaded ISOs for Windows XP and Windows 7, and tried setting up Windows XP. Some files apparently were corrupted so I decided to restart my PC.

(In hindsight, I should have scanned the files for viruses, I deleted them from my computer since I thought that they were useless and I needed to get other versions)

[image: When it starts back up, I'm greeted with this]

The same goes for the taskbar and inside folders.

I can't see any of the icons or images, just the file names.

The first thing I tried to do was to reboot it in Safe Mode, but it didn't work. I tried rebuilding the icon cache, but it didn't work either.

My friend suggested enabling and disabling tablet mode.

[image: Unfortunately, the option for enabling/disabling tablet mode was grayed out for me, so I couldn't do that.]

He also suggested unplugging both my monitors and my Cintiq (which is a drawing tablet), no luck there either.

I scanned my computer with Malware Bytes but no threats were found on my computer.

I also tried doing the "SFC /scannow" comamnd in the command prompt, but it said that it found nothing wrong.

The two other questions asked on this website that I could find weren't much help for me either, one of them was a duplicate and the other suggested that I disable tablet mode, which really didn't help for me.

To anyone who can help me with this problem, thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

IconCache.db is nowhere to be found in my Local folder in Appdata. I tried to recreate it, delete it, then restart my PC. Nothing changed. I also went to 'C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer' and deleted all the iconcache and thumbcache files then restarted my PC. That didn't solve the problem. I also forgot to mention that I use Windows 10.

**EDIT 2**
I tried using System Restore to reset my PC to a point before I installed my Virtual Machine, which was about a week ago. Sadly, that didn't help. I think there may be a problem within my files.

Comment: Do you have show desktop icons enabled? If you right click-desktop and go to view?

Comment: Yes I've tried that, I unchecked and checked "Show desktop icons" but nothing happened.
Another thing is that I can view everything fine when I try to upload files on websites like Imgur or Mediafire

Answer (score 1):

If everything in this thread fails i would suggest your run an elevated command prompt and type: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`

now i know you said you rebuilt cache, i am not sure how or what method or even if the method provided by Arthur Kamande , [Here](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/86123d1466514454-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a-rebuild_icon_cache.bat) is a batch file that will automate it for you, it might not be useful for you but can be for others if they face same issue .

Comment: I've tried your command but all that comes up is "No component store corruption detected"

Comment: The method I also used for rebuilding my icon cache was that batch file, sorry for not making it clear in my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only way I could fix this problem was resetting my computer.

I went to settings > update & security > recovery > advanced startup

I chose the option to keep all my files and I let my computer reset.

Thank you to those who helped me out and hopefully someone get this issue again.

Answer (score -1):

It could be that your icon cache is the issue . What I was thinking is that you can try to reset your icon cache you can try to rebuild it by going to this path
C:\Users(Your User Name)\AppData\Local 
once there you can delete IconCache.db file.
restart your machine it will recreate your icons.

Comment: OP has already stated that he tried to rebuild the icon cache /

Comment: Have you tried system restore it helps resolve some types of issues.

Comment: I tried restoring it to a point before I installed my VM, which was about a week ago. That didn't help, my icons and thumbnails are still missing.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I looked it up and I found a link that really helped me. It was a tutorial on how to fix this in windows 10. All you need to do is open up registry editor by doing <kbd>Win Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then typing:

```
regedit
```

Navigate to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

Find the one under that category labelled as `Shell Icons`. Then all you need to do is right click it, and  rename it or delete it. Either or will fix the problem.